# H2 RunScript SHOW TABLES doesn't find any table

Tags: h2

I have an h2 v1 DB which I'm trying to run SHOW TABLES from the command line as part of a verification process.  It's not finding any tables even though the H2 web console sees the tables.

```
$ cat showtable.sql 
SHOW TABLES;
$ java -cp ./h2-1.4.200.jar org.h2.tools.RunScript -url 'jdbc:h2:./agentdb-dev.mv.db' -script showtable.sql -showResults
SHOW TABLES;
;
```

If I use the H2 web console on the same file and run "SHOW TABLES" it shows everything it should.
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: `jdbc:h2:./agentdb-dev.mv.db` actually means `./agentdb-dev.mv.db.mv.db`, you shouldn't specify file extension in JDBC URL. Also this URL is relative to the current working directory and this directory can be different in different processes.

Comment: Yes! That's the problem. I forgot I shouldn't add the ".mv.db" to the file name!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Evgenji I needed to remove the ".mv.db" from the file name given since h2 adds that to whatever name is given.